# Show dial/call duration

Tags: calls

In Android 2.1 there was the possibility to drag the notifications bar during dialing a number and to be able to see when the phone started ringing (it was starting counting when connecting, then resetting the counter when dialing) and hence be able to "beep" somebody without listening the dialing sound. 
In Android 2.2 this function disappeared. Is there a way to bring it back or an app in the market for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, you want to get notified when a call goes through, not when the other person picks up? You could try Settings -> Call settings -> All calls -> Call status tones -> Call connect tone to get a sound from the speaker when the call connects, so you don't have to hold the phone to your ear. Is this what you were looking for?

Edit: I know, it doesn't answer the title but could help with the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't seem to find the menus from "All Calls" forward...I have HTC Legend. And, basically, I would prefer a visual feedback, not an audio one. I would like to be able to beep someone in "complete silence". But anyway, what happenned to the countdown which was present in Android 2.1? It was very useful.

Comment: Could be that the function is customized to my Samsung Galaxy S. Sorry I couldn't help, I've never paid attention to the counter.

Comment: @linkyndy There's an app called Spare Parts that might allow you to change the setting onik suggests.

Comment: OK, thank you for your suggestions. I will try. Is there any other more "official" way to achieve this?